# How do I combine data from multiple sheets in excel, but create new rows from each sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have multiple sheets, but the columns are standardized on each sheet. In other words, column A is always 'Name' on each of the sheets.

I want to consolidate the data in another sheet, but not concatenate the data, I want to create new rows for the rows on each sheet. So, if sheet 1 has 15 rows, then sheet 2 has 15 rows, then when I consolidate the data there would be 30 rows.

Comment: use power query, just remember to refresh the consolidated sheet after updating any other sheet.

Comment: @gns100 - im using someone else's data, so I can't update their sheets but some seem to have errors. I'm getting the error "Invalid cell value '#N/A'." any ideas?

Comment: If you are just pulling data, without you doing updates, then power query IS the way to go. You can put the power query in a separate workbook so as not to mess with the data entry workbook(s). As for the errors I'm not sure, it may be that the someone entered text in a number field. This data scrubbing is another question, but seeing that error is the trigger to has you talking with the data entry person to clean up their data...

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use a special [Combine Sheets](https://www.ablebits.com/excel-suite/combine-sheets.php) tool. It can merge data from several worksheets into a single Excel sheet based on column headers.
Select worksheets you want to merge. Decide which columns will be copied to a new table. Select to insert results to new worksheets or range. Multiple tables are combined into one according to their column headers.
This is a paid solution, but much faster and easier than Power Query. You can try the trial version for free.

It is available as a part of Ultimate Suite for Excel.

Comment: This is paid extra software, there has to be a different solution. Please elaborate on why you think this is the best solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would definitely prefer not to pay for a solution.